# Shuffle only selected items in an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array right here

**I would like to shuffly only answerA, answerB, answerC and answerD fields for each object.**
So I get back an array where answerA might be answerB, answerC might be answerD etc etc.

What is a simple way to do this?

Comment: How do you construct the objects?

Comment: @blueygh2 It comes from a PHP query and transformed to JSarray with json_encode.

Comment: Can you modify the way php constructs the objects? If so, I'd suggest using an array of answers in each "question" object. Then you can more easily shuffle the answers around in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `shuffleArray` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12646864/989121:

```
   myKeys = ['answerA','answerB','answerC','answerD']
   myValues = myKeys.map(function(k) { return myObject[k] })
   myValues = shuffleArray(myValues)
   myKeys.forEach(function(k) { myObject[k] = myValues.shift() })
```

That said, a simpler option would be to structure your object like this:

```
ID: 22
answers: [
    "first", "second answer", etc
],
category: ...
etc
```

Serially named variables is always an indicator that you actually need an array.

Comment: I still didn't get how the function can work with my above array. I want to keep my array as it is except for each object to shuffle only answerA-D.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: if you want a complete solution, post your array as javascript, or make a fiddle.

Comment: Well the function would be pretty much something that gets an array as a parameter with the fields exactly as they are above, and it return an array with shuffled answersA-D. I would gladly post a JSFiddle but my array gets returned via PHP so it would be a tad hard for me to do that.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: in the above code, `myObject` is a single array element, to apply it to the whole array, use `myArray.forEach(function(myObject) { code })`.

Comment: so considering my array is called myObject, how do I feed it in the function? I tried console.log(myArray.forEach(function(myObject)...etc)